# AutomationAnywhere VBScript

Tags: vbscript, rpa, automationanywhere

Hello I am trying to upload VBScript to filter out only data that has been changed. When I am using script as a Macro it works but when I am launching it via AAE it throws an

> Error In Script 1024 Expected Statement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUB34.jpg)

```
Sub filtering()
    Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Q3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("P3").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("A1").Value
    Operator:=xlAND Criteria2:="<=" & Range("A2").Value   
End Sub
```

Comment: With the exclusive command available for excel in command library you should be able to use AAE inbuilt command to achieve what you are trying from VB

Comment: Or Convert the VB Macro to Add In Button and make the bot click the button ( Which runs the macro)

Comment: Hello Clint, 
But the problem is that I will have everyday new file created, so I wanted to automatically run the VB script from AAE to chosen excel file. Do you see any solution how to do that? 

Solution that I was also thinking about is to convert excel file into SQL query and then work with SQL instead of excel what I think will be faster but I'm not sure what consequences might happened.

Comment: I think its best to consider using the existing VB script, now the question is how you will make AAE to run this script of a new file every day. To do this we can easily create a add in button that  runs your VB script .

Comment: How you want to create a add button you mean in excel file, that runs macro after clicking it ?

It's kind of brut force solution, but I also thought about making bot for writing VB script to new open file and then use a function in AAE "run macro".

Comment: If the solution helped, please mark it as answered so that it may also help others in the community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to solve this :

---

**First:**

---

Lets include the subroutine withing within the `<script>` tag

```
<script type="text/vbscript">

Sub filtering()
    Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Q3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("P3").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("A1").Value
    Operator:=xlAND Criteria2:="<=" & Range("A2").Value   
End Sub

</script>
```

Or  ignore the Subroutines entirely and include the below snippet in the .vbs file in AAE

```
Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("Q3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("P3").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("A1").Value
Operator:=xlAND Criteria2:="<=" & Range("A2").Value
```

---

***Second:***

You can the add the script in as an Add-in button in the form of Ribbons
And in AAE you can instruct the button to click on the button by using the `Object Cloning` from the command library.

For example:
How the button looks like from Excel Ribbons

[image]

The Code module in the back end

[image]

---